# Yahoo Finance API finally dead? Using ichart GET call?

Tags: yahoo-finance

It looks like the party is over with regard to historical data from the Yahoo Finance API. I've followed previous answers and nothing is working. The previous code was of the format:

```
http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL
```

and even https.

```
https://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL
```

None of these resolve in browser or can be requested. For historical data is there any API in existence for Yahoo Finance? It's possible to get current data points with the following calls:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=e
```

However no history. Any suggestions or functioning work around?

Answer (score 0):

Try the spreadsheets here:
[Bulk Yahoo historical stock quote downloader](http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/)
[Historical stock prices from Yahoo](http://www.signalsolver.com/download-historic-stock-price-data-excel/)

Yahoo finance now uses a cookie-crumb pair. The VBA in the spreadsheets

1. gets the cookie-crumb pair from Yahoo for a junk call
2. uses the cookie-crumb pair to download historical data

uses the cookie-crumb pair to download historical data.

The first spreadsheet lets you download bulk data. The second spreadsheet contains a wrapper function that converts old Yahoo Finance API calls to a format that still works

The VBA is more involved (not a clean API call anymore), and Yahoo may shut off this route without notice. But, for now, you can still get historical data.